# Передача сообщения

Tags: facebook, twitter, сеть, вконтакте

Кто знает, как происходит передача сообщений в соц.сетях.
Вроде создается 2 таблицы

1 ussers

2 massage

И таблица massage должна содержать (id отправителя)(id получателя)(и само сообщения)??
И как сделать так что-бы возле сообщения писалась дата?

Comment: сори за оффтоп,но название таблицы massage доставляет)))

Comment: massage доставляет 

Сорри я не понял, что ты имел ввиду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Юзер А создаёт сообщение(т.е. запись в БД), где в поле отправитель значится сам, а в поле получатель - тот, кому сообщение отправляется(юзер Б). Юзер Б проверяет входящие(делает выборку из БД по полю "получатель").
Вот и весь механизм, всё просто.

Comment: А что-бы возле сообщения писалась дата, это еще одно поле в БД должно быть и там ты должен сохранять время?

Comment: Конечно. + булевы поля для отслеживания за тем, прочитал ли юзер сообщение или нет. И т.д. и т.п....

Comment: Еще неплохо сделать булевские поля типа `sender_delete`, `payer_delete`.
Чтобы можно было сделать возможность удаления сообщений. 

Т.е., выборка делается типа `WHERE sender_delete=0` для отправителя и

`WHERE sender_delete=0` для получвателя

Таким образом реально из БД сообщения должны удалятся только тогда когда оба поля = 1(true). При этом можно сэмулировать удаление сообщений для получателей и отправителей.

При удалении соответственно отправителем делается `SET sender_delete=1`, получателем `SET payer_delete=1`.

Comment: так таких типов: sender_delete, payer_delete  в mysql нету

Comment: @Zow - вы меня не поняли, это tinyint поля длиной в 1, либо ENUM 0,1.

А слово **типа** подразумевало "как-то так", "что-то наподобии" и т.д.

Т.е. у вас есть 2 поля в каждом из них вы храните 0 - для не удаленных и 1 - для "удаленных". Действительно удаляете сообщение только тогда когда оба этих поля = 1.

Примерно так же делается с полями просмотра сообщения. Делается 0,1 поле, если его значение = 0 - сообщение не прочитано, если 1 - прочитано.

Теперь поняли?:)

Comment: да) спс)))